# Monotonicity of function $f(x)=(1+\frac1x)^x(1+x)^\frac1x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, monotone-functions

Given function for $x>0$

$$f(x)=(1+\frac1x)^x(1+x)^\frac1x$$

which is not a monotonic function, but it is easy to find the only maxima

$$f(1)=4$$

so, can we find a strict prove showing $f(x)$ is monotonic increasing for interval $(0,1)$, and monotonic decreasing for interval $(1,\infty)$?

actually, I already try to do the logarithm of the function shows

$$\ln f(x)=x\ln(1+\frac1x)+\frac1x\ln(1+x)$$

but, it still seems not convenient to reach the monotonicity, even take the derivative of $\ln f(x)$, especially for interval $(0,1)$. I may need some further suggestions here.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write your $f(x)$ in the form
$$f(x)=\frac{(1+x)^x\cdot (1+x)^{1/x}}{x^x}$$ and take the logarithm of your $f(x)$
$$\ln(f(x))=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln(x+1)-x\ln(x)$$